# how to set windowonfocuschange() event in android

Tags: android

i have an image view whose image should keep on changing every 5 seconds when the window in which it is drawn has focus. when the window loses focus then the thread that was changing the image should close.

for the above to happen i need to implement the onwindowfocuschange(boolean haswindowfocus) method, but i don't know how to implement the same

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ViewFlipper and in onPause() method you may call stopFlipping() which will stop that. onPause is called when your activity loses focus

Comment: i am using async task right now and inside the timer i am using timertask to change the image of the imageview every 4 seconds.

Comment: what i want to say is you can do the same thing using inbuilt components you don't need to use asynctask to just flip images every 4 seconds and stop it while loosing focus